# Searchbar from react-native-paper course view error

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

Every time I add in a searchbar from react-native-paper to my app, I continue to get two of these errors/warnings:

WARN  (ADVICE) View #49 of type ABI48_0_0RCTView has a shadow set but cannot calculate shadow efficiently. Consider setting a background color to fix this, or apply the shadow to a more specific component.
WARN  (ADVICE) View #47 of type ABI48_0_0RCTView has a shadow set but cannot calculate shadow efficiently. Consider setting a background color to fix this, or apply the shadow to a more specific component.

With it only being a warning, it's not bothering anything, other than driving me crazy; however, I would really like to fix it. I've tried adding a background color to everything I can possiblity add and it still hasn't fixed this issue.  Here is my page:

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import { Searchbar } from "react-native-paper";

export const TestScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>
      <Searchbar placeholder="Search" style={{ backgroundColor: "#800080" }} />
      <Text style={{ margin: 60 }}>Test Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```